# Can you train your set on a separate dataframe than the one you use to test your set with? (Python)

Tags: python, linear-regression, training-data, train-test-split

for a school project I need to make a forecast of the baseline sales. I've splitted the dataset into a X and Y set. X = all my variables except Total units (baseline), Y = Total Units (baseline).

I would love to train my set on the weeks where there are no promotions = (FINAL_df[FINAL_df['PROMOTIONAL_PRESENCE']==0]), and test my set on all the weeks (and not only the weeks without promotion = FINAL_df) this should give a better result than if I train them both on the same set (FINAL_df).

But I have no idea how to train the training set separately from the test set?

( I know this part of my code is wrong: X_train = FINAL_df[FINAL_df['PROMOTIONAL_PRESENCE']==0], but I don't know how to correct it?)

(I am new to coding and ML so any help is very much appreciated!) Thanks in advance!

code:

```
X = FINAL_df.drop(["Total_Units"],axis="columns")
Y = FINAL_df.Total_Units

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train = FINAL_df[FINAL_df['PROMOTIONAL_PRESENCE']==0]

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2, random_state=101)

lin_model = LinearRegression()

lin_model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

--> here i get an error (Unable to allocate 3.48 GiB for an array with shape (453971, 1028) and data type float64)**strong text**

Comment: Please add your system specification like OS and memory and size of data you are training model for. for now you can check datatype of features try to make it slim if possible.

Comment: To work with the data easier, convert to Float32 data-type. Do `X = FINAL_df.drop(["Total_Units"],axis="columns").astype('float32')`

Comment: Thank you both, @JAbr where can I find the system specifications that you asked? And @YScharf thank you for the input but I get another error now, this one definitely has something to do with the: `X_train FINAL_df[FINAL_df['PROMOTIONAL_PRESENCE']==0]`. The error i get now is: 'Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [453971, 495379]'.
Any idea how I can correct this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: okay i'll try to clarify the problem. So I have a X-set with all the predictors and a Y-set with 'Total_units', the variable I want to predict. The array for my normal dataframe; ‘FINAL_df’ looks like: `X_train: (495379, 1027)
Y_train: (495379,)
X_test: (123845, 1027)
Y_test: (123845,)`
But i don't want to use FINAL_df for both training and testing. For the TRAINING of my set i only want to use the weeks without a promotion, the code for the weeks without promotion is: `FINAL_df[FINAL_df['PROMOTIONAL_PRESENCE']==0]`

Comment: For the TESTING,I want to test the dataset on all the weeks (which is just my normal dataframe: FINAL_df). But if use the code as shown above with: X_train FINAL_df[FINAL_df['PROMOTIONAL_PRESENCE']==0], i will get this array: `X_train: (453971, 1028) Y_train: (495379,) X_test: (123845, 1027) Y_test: (123845,)` and the error code: 'Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [453971, 495379]' So the questions is really: how can i train my set on a slightly different set `(FINAL_df[FINAL_df['PROMOTIONAL_PRESENCE']==0])` and test this on the main set (FINAL_df)?

Comment: X_train first dimension should be equal to Y_train, copy the indices which you dropped and drop from the same rows from Y_train as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

FINAL_df_prom_pres0 = FINAL_df[FINAL_df['PROMOTIONAL_PRESENCE']==0]

Y = FINAL_df_prom_pres0.Total_Units
X = FINAL_df_prom_pres0.drop(["Total_Units"],axis="columns")


from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2, random_state=101)

lin_model = LinearRegression()

lin_model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

I changed the answer can you please try like this.

Comment: Thanks JAbr, but i get another error if i try this, now i get this: `KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([    94,    188,    190,    205,    215,    219,    238,    239,\n               246,    253,\n            ...\n            619214, 619215, 619216, 619217, 619218, 619219, 619220, 619221,\n            619222, 619223],\n           dtype='int64', length=453971)] are in the [columns]"`

I just think the `X_train = FINAL_df[FINAL_df['PROMOTIONAL_PRESENCE']==0]` part is not right or needs to be formulated differently, but of course I am not sure.

Comment: @ JAbr thanks again for the input! This time the linear regression worked, but for your example,  aren't the weeks without promo also used in the testing? ( instead of both the weeks with promo and without promo) Or am I wrong?

Comment: The X and Y variable now contain rows where promotional presence is zero. This is as per your example, you can change accordingly also the problem was mismatched dimensions of X and Y, please dont forget to upvote the answer. Thanks